# Mount new partition over top of live data

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian-wheezy

On my server, I have a tiny root partition that is now full up. I removed the swap from the hard drive that has the root partition, and moved the swap onto a RAID 0 partition. I now want to use the new space for my `/var` directory.

I deleted the swap partition, and created the new one, and enabled it with `mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/sda2`. The partition is created. Now, I want to mount it to `/var` without losing the data that's currently on it. I need to be able to do it via SSH, and I need to do with being completely headless, as I do not have the ability to plug in a monitor to it.

I have tried running `mount /dev/sda2 /var`, but the contents of the old `/var` directory is still there, on the original `/dev/sda1`, which is full. **How can I move the data over, and set `/dev/sda2` as my `/var` directory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something I miss,because it does not seem so difficult to me... in which case pls bear with me if I am being thick.

It seems to me you could do it like this:

1. mount your brand new partition to a new mount point, let's call it */mount* (you will have to create it, of course);
2. copy all files from /var to /mount with the *-p* option, so as to preserve permissions, as kindly suggested by @Lawrence below;
3. Fix /etc/fstab so that, at next reboot, /dev/sda2 is mounted at /var;
4. Rename the old /var directory to, say, /var-old, without emptying it just yet,
5. Reboot, check everything is in order, empty /var-old

Comment: Renamed the folder, tried executing a reboot, but it's just hanging. It takes keyboard input still, but no commands are running. I'll try to reboot it with the keyboard, just need to bring home a monitor first

Comment: OK, it worked for me. I did have to redo all the permissions manually though, I'd insert that between steps 3 and 4 though.

Comment: if you copy with the `-p` argument, then all permissions are preserved.